# Mono-Component on my Synology-DiskStation: System.DllNotFoundException libgdiplus.so.0

Tags: c#, .net, mono, gdi+, synology

Before the last update of the `Mono-Component`, everything works fine!
 But now I have very much problems with my `ASP.NET-Pages` written in `C#`!

More Details:

```
 Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
 Details: Non-web exception.
 Exception stack trace:
 at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Drawing.GDIPlus:GdiplusStartup (ulong&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupInput&,System.Drawing.GdiplusStartupOutput&)
 at System.Drawing.GDIPlus..cctor () [0x000cc] in <1917aa1c39d94b1a91807b8cd9f03350>:0

Version Information: 4.6.2 (Stable 4.6.2.16/ac9e222 Mon Feb 20 21:24:22 CST 2017); ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.42000
```

There is no problem locally at my `IIS` with the same Code!!!

Comment: please format the code/errors...

Comment: DLL mappings are in /volume1/@appstore/Mono/usr/local/etc/mono/config but even after creating symbolic link `ln -s /volume1/@appstore/Mono/usr/local/lib/libgdiplus.so.0.0.0 /usr/lib/libgdiplus.so.0` it still didn't work for me.

Comment: Downgrading Mono from [4.6.2](https://archive.synology.com/download/Package/spk/Mono/4.6.2-0095/) to [4.2.1](https://archive.synology.com/download/Package/spk/Mono/4.2.1-0089/) resolved the problem for me.